# office365user sending mails to office 365 user mail logs?

Tags: email, office365

I want to know how can i get email information regarding two office 365 users.I want to log email send by an office 365 user to another 365 user.Where can i get that.?I have integrated office 365 to my SIEM and currently have management,sharepoint logs.Please help

Comment: Can you add more details regarding your problem, your environnement and what solutions you tried before ?

Comment: thanks for reply.How can i track when a office 365 user send a mail to another office 365 user.currently we are injecting management and sharepoint logs from office 365 using API to our siem,but it dont have these details